# Express route param breaks on params containing "@"

Tags: express

Have a very simple express route

```
router.get('/compare/:packages', function(req, res, next) {
  const packages = req.params.packages.split(',');
  res.render('index', { title: "title" });
});
```

When accessing it with something that contains an @ sign, it doesn't match and returns a 404, help?

```
/compare/elm,@cycle/run
```

edit: This worked

```
router.get('/compare/:packages*', function(req, res, next) {
  const packages = req.params.packages.split(',');
  res.render('index', { title: "title" });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the `@`, it's the `/` before `/run`, because by default, parameters will be delimited by slashes.

You can use this:

```
router.get('/compare/*', function(req, res, next) {
  const packages = req.params[0].split(',');
  res.render('index', { title: "title" });
});
```

Comment: thanks! led me down the right path. Adding a trailing * fixed my problem